# Swift 4: Array for all types of Ints and Floating point numbers

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4

I have a program that working with all kind of Ints and Floating pointer value types

Is there is a way to create array that will holds all kind of those values in it?

I have tried to do this via protocol and extend Int and Double with them but no luck because of protocol equability limitation in Swift(or something like this)

```
protocol ArrayStructValue: Comparable,Equatable { }

extension Double: ArrayStructValue{}

extension Int:ArrayStructValue {}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the issues you have with the protocol solution (which is supposed to be the most  reasonable one)

Comment: I wonder, why don't you just convert everything to `Double`?

Comment: @vadian Do not judge me quickly, I am new in Swift and iOS so maybe my way is not right

Comment: Both `Double` and `Int` already conform to `Comparable` and `Equatable`. If you remove the constraints the code will compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want two different types in one array, why don't you use a union, e.g. using an `enum`:

```
enum MyNumber {
    case integer(Int)
    case double(Double)
}

let numbers: [MyNumber] = [.integer(10), .double(2.0)]
```

However, in most situations it would be probably better to just convert all `Int` into `Double` and just have a `[Double]` array.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson buddy ! ;)

Comment: I agree with you, that was my solution. But, in my case all values in this array are calculated and any time the calculated values are different. In some situation when I init my [Double] array with those values I started to get : Could not cast value of type Swift.Int to Swift.double. Then I broke my head and decide to ask you guys here

Comment: @AlexBerd You would have to cast explicitly, e.g. `Double(intValue)` or `Int(doubleValue)`.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @vadian both types `Int` and `Double` already conforms to `Strideable` which inherits from `Comparable` which inherits from `Equatable` so there is no need to constrain your protocol to them. So all you need is to make `Int` and `Double inherit from your protocol:

```
protocol ArrayStructValue { }
extension Double: ArrayStructValue { }
extension Int: ArrayStructValue { }

var f: [ArrayStructValue] = []
f.append(1)
f.append(2.0)

type(of: f[0])  // Int.Type
type(of: f[1])  // Double.Type
```